# How can I change place of y label on pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to change place of ylabel near the axes.[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See the `ylabel shift` option, which can be used to move the label by an amount, for example

```
\begin{axis}[ylabel shift = 1 pt]
  ...
\end{axis}
```

(You will need to have `\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}` or a higher version number for this to work.)

Comment: Shouldn't also be set `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}`?

Comment: @Claudio I've added that comment. I always use the latest settings, so this is not something I have to worry about normally.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I did not know this fact :)

Comment: Setting `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}` (or higher) will automatically move the label "as close as possible" (i.e. near the boundary of the largest tick label). Perhaps you do not even need a custom shift (although it might be necessary if tick labels have signs which increase the bounding box).

Answer (score 28):

Try to add the `ylabel near ticks` option in the `axis` environment like this

```
\begin{axis}[..., ylabel near ticks, ...]
  ...
\end{axis}
```

There is no need to give a value for this option.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The previous answer did not solve the problem, but the `ylabel near ticks` did.

Answer (score 7):

The following code shall works for you

```
%----------------------------------------------
\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.style={
cells={anchor=center},% Centered entries
inner xsep=3pt,
inner ysep=2pt,
nodes={inner sep=2pt,text depth=0.15em},
anchor=south east,
shape=rectangle, %box shape
fill=white, %box inside
draw=white, %box color
at={(rel axis cs:0.90,1.0)} %box position right top
}}

%-------------------------------------------
\begin{axis}
[
 ylabel style={yshift=0.4cm}, %shifting the y line text
]
```