# Wrong position of arrows in Tikz with pgfplots version 1.3

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows, bugs

I use the following code to draw an arrow in Tikz with `\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10,ylabel={Some values},ylabel shift = -10pt]
            \draw[->,thick] (3,3) -- (4,4);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but I get the arrow at a wrong location. I need to use at least the version 1.3 because I need the command  `ylabel shift` to shift the label on `pgfplots` (as adviced in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54348/163249)).

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Add `axis cs:` to `\draw[->,thick] (650,66) -- (530,69);` like `\draw[->,thick] (axis cs:650,66) -- (axis cs:530,69);.`

Comment: upgrade this ancient `pgfplots` version with recent  1.16 :-). it has beside all from 1.3 all (a lot of) improvements ... and show an example with command `ylabel shift`.

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem with `axis cs:`. I use `\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}` as advised in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54348/163249) for `ylabel shift`.

Comment: In the cited answer it say "(You will need to have \pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3} **or a higher version number** for this to work.)", emphasis mine. So 1.16 is OK, because 16 is greater than 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be solved by adding `axis cs:` to `\draw[->,thick] (650,66) -- (530,69)`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10,ylabel={Some values},ylabel shift = -10pt]
            \draw[->,thick] (axis cs:3,3) -- (axis cs:4,4);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As suggested in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477282/wrong-position-of-arrows-in-tikz-with-pgfplots-version-1-3/477291#comment1205026_477282).

Another possible solution is to use a a higher version of `pgfplots` (`\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10,ylabel={Some values},ylabel shift = -10pt]
            \draw[->,thick] (3,3) -- (4,4);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As suggested in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477282/wrong-position-of-arrows-in-tikz-with-pgfplots-version-1-3#comment1205030_477282).

Comment: (i) but you should show where and how you use `ylabel shift`, (ii) you should first ask @ferahfeza that convert his comment to answer ...

Comment: ... And in a recent pgfplot, you'll have both `ylabel shift` and axis cs as a default. I think that the OP is thinking that 1.3 is greater than 1.16...For  which I can sympathize  with.

Comment: I have added how to use `ylabel shift`, and merged in the solution the possibility of using a higher version of `pgfplots`. How should I contact the users to write the answers?

Comment: @Rmano yes I was indeed confused, I thought 1.3>1.16... Thanks for your help!